# meta tag viewport makes my website look very weird on ipad

Tags: html, ipad, mobile, meta-tags, viewport

'Sup Stack!

So I've been getting to grips with the viewport meta tag and how it adjusts pages to fit to the devices viewport. I've had some help from stackoverflow earlier here:
[Footer will not extend to 100% width on iphone, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11439954/footer-will-not-extend-to-100-width-on-iphone-why)
mainly my concern was that my footer for my website wouldn't extend to 100% width. You can visit the website here:
http://gloryillustration.com/
And you can see my iphone solution here:
http://gloryillustration.com/tests/test13.html
where i managed to sort the webpage to display properly on iphone, by using:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0">
```

And if you were to view this on the ipad the footer *is* displaying 100% width, but the entire page is now displaying as though its zoomed waaaaay out and its adding tons of white space to the right left of the page and *under* the footer as well. I take it that the website is adjusting itself as though it is being viewed on an iphone. But im not sure *why* it's  adjusting like that? I would think that the content="device-width" would set the width to that of the device its being viewed on? Or have i misunderstood this completely.

Is there a way to set a viewport meta tag to encompass both ipads *and* iphones for this website?

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
```

You can see the result in play here http://www.premiumdw.com/case-studies/convert-a-960-grid-website-to-a-responsive-design/.

Answer (score 0):

try initial-scale=1 instead of 0

for you wanna have it a 100% zoom, not 0%

Comment: I've tried that already, initial scale 1 is what is causing the earlier footer problem. also it scales the website a bit weird as well, and also makes it display weird on iphones. So it would be a step back for me to do this.